# Is this an Strategy Pattern implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have built a software architecture and now I wonder if it can be considered to match some knowed design pattern:

All layers are composed of multiple interfaces that contain small pieces of logic:

`HasService` indicates that a class contains an `EntityService` implementation of some `E` and `Q` type.

```
public interface HasService<E extends BaseEntity, Q extends QueryParams> {
    EntityService<E, Q> getService();
}
```

`InsertDtoEndpoint`indicates that a class has the ability to receive a json input formated as `D`, map it to `E`, insert it and then map it back to `D` before return it.

```
public interface InsertDtoEndpoint<E extends AbstractBaseEntity, D extends Dto, Q extends QueryParams>
    extends Endpoint, HasService<E, Q> {

    @POST
    default Response insert(D dto) {
        return ok(executeInsert(dto));
    }

    default D executeInsert(D dto) {
        E mapped = mapInsertRequestRecordToPersistentEntity(dto);
        return mapInsertResponseRecordToDto(getService().save(mapped));
    }

    E mapInsertRequestRecordToPersistentEntity(D dto);
    D mapInsertResponseRecordToDto(E entity);

}
```

Then the actual endpoints which are accessed via http calls are composed of a composition of these interfaces:

```
public class SomeEntityEndpoint implements InsertDtoEndpoint<SomeEntity, SomeDto, DefaultQueryParam>, FetchEndpoint<SomeEntity, DefaultQueryParams>, FindEndpoint<SomeEntity, DetailedDto, DefaultQueryParams> {

    SomeEntity mapInsertRequestRecordToPersistentEntity(SomeDto dto) { 
        //map to entity 
    }

    SomeDto mapInsertResponseRecordToDto(SomeEntity entity) {
        //map to dto
    }

    DetailedDto mapFindResponseRecordToDto(SomeEntity entity) {
        //Map to dto
    }

    getService() {
        //Return service..
    }

 }
```

Comment: So you want to know what Design Pattern your code follows? Did you follow a pattern to make it or just coded randomly with your good practices? Design Patterns are NOT something one alone can create, they represent the *best practices* that the community has found to work that comply with **Design Principles** (like low coupling, fragility, etc.). It may be the case that your code seems *similar* to a known Pattern, but it is highly unlikely that you used a Design Pattern without knowing it.

Comment: Well... this is just implementing an interface, thus it is simple decoupling. Of course, the strategy pattern is based on decoupled code, but the idea with the strategy pattern is that you change the strategy on the fly (i.e. while the program is running).

Comment: @GrayCygnus "it is highly unlikely that you used a Design Pattern without knowing it." from my experience, this is wrong. I know a lot of people who, e.g., used the Factory Pattern without anyone (this includes books and google) teaching them. Same holds for Composition Pattern, Strategy Pattern, Object Pooling, Adapters, Decorators,....

Comment: @Turing85, template maybe?

Comment: @GrayCygnus got your point btw

Comment: @GrayCygnus "Design Patterns are NOT something one alone can create, they represent the best practices that the community has found to work that comply with Design Principles". Where did you get this information? The impression I have got is that a lot of design patterns are originating from "Design Patterns, Elements of Object-Oriented Reusable Software" by the gang of four. They may not have come up with them all but it is by far the most complete collection. Also constructs rarely follows the school book completely and most constructs are a combination of multiple design patterns.

Comment: @GrayCygnus Edited the introduction based on your comments

Comment: @MarcosJ.CKichel If you want to put a lable on your code, then yes. I think the template pattern would fit. But remember that things like "interfaces without a method" already count as a "pattern" (Marker). So... a fancy name does not make your code "better". Stay humble =)

Comment: @patrik Design Principles (like the ones Turing85 mentioned: low coupling, modularity, open/close principle) are the "motivation" of creating Design Patterns (like factory, Decorator, Strategy...). These pattern try to mitigate common software drawbacks and implementation difficulties, in an efficient and scalable way. They usually reflect the best practices that have proven to work on those problems. Check [this](http://unpetitaccident.com/pub/compeng/languages/JAVA/Principles_and_Patterns.pdf) if you would like to know more about them

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for your advice, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @GrayCygnus Thanks for sharing

Comment: @Turing85 You are correct, it is common that some enterprises have implemented projects without knowing the "official" name of the Pattern. I made a mistake, and actually wanted to say "it is highly unlikely that you *created a new* a Design Pattern without knowing it.

Comment: @Turing85 If you'd like to write an answer based on your last comment I'd be happy to accept it :)

Comment: @GrayCygnus but I never said I've created a new design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let it be mentioned that there are different levels of patterns. I am not speaking about the types (like creational, structural, behavioural...) but the actual impact on your codebase. On the one hand, there are Patterns like the [Marker Interface Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) (basically an empty interface) which have little to no impact on your code. On the other hand, there are patterns like [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), which have a major impact on your overall design.

Your code shows basic decoupling by implementing interfaces. Thus if it follows a pattern, it would be one of the "smaller" patterns.

The [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) you mentioned is based on decoupled code. But the core of the Strategy Pattern is that you change the strategy while the program is running. An example would be changing the AI of some game (let's pick StarCraft for the sake of it) in response to recognising that the opponent is significantly weakter/stronger and a more defensive/offensive behaviour would be beneficial. Your code seems to implement some web-service (or at least some data transfers between processes). Normally you do not re-define how your object is transferred, so I would not call this a Strategy Pattern.

As you mentioned in the comments, the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) would fit. Your server defines when to send what (or at least, this is how I imagine it) and calls the concrete Endpoints to delegate the actual work.

Overall, labeling your code with pattern names is not the goal. You should choose the right tool for the job. Some patterns are more suitable for some tasks than others. Sometimes a solution following none of the known patterns may even be more elegant/readable/performant/whatever your metric is. In this case, do not try to squeeze your solution in a pattern just to have this big fancy name tag on top of it (this usually leads to over-engeneering). [Sometimes, simple code is more elegant than every pattern.](https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/apqNxqD_700b_v4.jpg)